# Grub rescue error when booting

Tags: boot

I was using Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8, but I deleted the Ubuntu from the C drive where it was installed and deleted and formatted the partition as well. I extended the C drive with its previous partition. Now, when I restart my PC the screen shows `grub rescue error: no partition`. How can I completely delete Ubuntu and restore it to Windows 8 again?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this several ways:

1 - Simply reinstall Windows 8, it will format and occupy entire disc;

2 - You have to use an Ubuntu Rescue CD do boot and remove Grub

3 - Using Windows DVD do a recovery system